# how to generate libssl.so and libcrypto.so from openSSL using encryption and decryption using JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I want to use libssl.so and libcrypto.so for encryption and decryption of files using JNI in Android. But, I am not able to get these two libraries from open SSL. So, how to get these two libraries please help me.

As, I download the openSSL Guardian Project from https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android. After add this open SSL project into my small Android Application. I build that project but I didn't find any libssl.so and libcrypto.so libraries. So, please help me how I can get built libssl.so and libcrytpo.so so that I can move on further steps for doing encryption and decryption using JNI in Android.

Comment: Why?  What part of your requirement isn't satisfied by the Java API?

Comment: _"So, how to get these two libraries please help me."_ You can download the [openssl source code](http://openssl.org/source/) and use the [makefiles found in the Android source tree](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl/+/master) as a basis for your own makefiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I didn't generate libssl.so and libcrypto.so library from openSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315379/i-didnt-generate-libssl-so-and-libcrypto-so-library-from-openssl)

Comment: page not found ^

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to make sure you get the version of openssl that you want, and that is why you are trying to compile it yourself.

In general, compiling an Android projects which are commonly built on a more "normal" linux variant than Android can require fiddling.  It seems that the openssl folks have a set of instructions here:

http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

To start, you will need to get an appropriate Android NDK and create a standalone toolchain for the type of device you want to deploy on.  The wiki page above seems to have instructions for compiling openssl using such a toolchain, e.g., setting CC=[gcc-version-from-your-toolchain], etc.

It is a little bit difficult to tell from you post why exactly you need to do this, and I agree with EJP's comment that depending on your need, there may be an easier path than compiling a new version of openssl yourself.